# Why is the rms value of an ac current always less than its peak value?

Tags: electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

(b) The current in a 2.5μF capacitor connector to an ac source is given by
I = – 4.71 sin 377t μA
Calculate the maximum voltage across the capacitor.

Comment: To explain the question from your title: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/rms-voltage.html

Comment: The question in your title is asking : why is the average of a set of values, which are not all the same, always less than the maximum of those values?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the rms value of an ac current always less than its peak value?

The power delivered by an AC current to a load at any given moment is proportional to the square of its value at that moment.

Since the value of the AC current is constantly changing, the instantaneous power delivered by the current is changing as well, reaching its maximum when the current is at its peak value. However, if we keep measuring the power over some period of time, we can calculate the average power.

Obviously, we can come up with a constant current (DC), which would deliver the same average power. The rms value of the AC current is defined as the value of that DC current, i.e., a DC current, which produces the same average power as the AC current.

Now it should be obvious that the rms value of an AC current could not be greater than its peak value, since, if that was the case, it would mean that the AC current could produce an average power exceeding its peak power.

> The current in a 2.5μF capacitor connector to an ac source is given by
>   I = – 4.71 sin 377t μA Calculate the maximum voltage across the
>   capacitor.

All you have to know here is the formula for the impedance of a capacitor and the relationship between the magnitudes (maximum values) of the voltage and the current.